# Word, expression for copying someone who inspires you

Tags: expressions, word-usage, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

All of us have a person; our elder siblings or friends or any one who we are inspired by. 
For example my elder sister, I love the way she carries herself, her personality, her poise, that I try my best to copy her. So my question is how would i say, any specific word for this? That I'm always trying to imitate her style

Comment: *Idol?* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idol See also my comment at oerkelens below.

Comment: "At only seventeen years old, she became a very popular idol and role model for young women in African American popular culture, and continues to claim admiring attention when she appears in public." (on Jordin Sparks 2007 American Idol) https://books.google.co.in/books?id=10rEGSIItjgC&dq=%22idol+and+role+model%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: @kris is there any phrasal verb/ expression for idol

Comment: "My hero." Also, "He was the **Beau Idéal** of the Regular Army" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beau-id%C3%A9al

Comment: I want to suggest *to study [your sister's] every move* as an expression. I think it has the diligence, thoroughness, and attention-to-detail you're looking for, but I can't find a source explicitly saying that the study is actually put into practice. I have seen it used in that way though, as this [article](http://www.latimes.com/sports/usc/uscnow/la-sp-usc-linebacker-michael-hutchings-is-prepared-for-his-first-start-20140910-story.html) quotes one football player talking about his inspiration: "I study his every move…. I prepare every game like I’m him."

Answer (score 4):

You are always *emulating* her.

(Verb)

> to try to equal or excel; imitate with effort to equal or surpass:
>
> to emulate one's father as a concert violinist....
>
> Sons often emulate their fathers.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emulate

(Some dictionaries define it as equalling or excelling [not trying to].  So sometimes people use *try/trying to emulate* to convey this meaning.)

Answer (score 1):

That would be your **role model**. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/role%20model) tells us:

> someone who another person admires and tries to be like

Comment: +1 However, it'd be good if there's a single word/ term for *idol* + *role model* which is more like what the OP refers to.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of phrasal verbs you can consider:

***model oneself on***

> Take (someone admired or respected) as an example to copy:
>
> *he models himself on rock legend Elvis Presley*
>
> [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/model)

***pattern yourself on sb/sth (BrE)***

> to copy something or someone:
>
> *She patterns herself on her big sister.*
>
> [[Cambridge]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pattern-yourself-on-sb-sth)

---

There are common phrases like *follow someone's lead* or *follow/tread in someone's footstep*s but they are usually used when you do the  same job or the same things in your life as someone else, especially a family member.