# What is the word when you admire someone and you do whatever he does in his life

Tags: word-choice, non-native-english

The person you follow can be a famous person or simply one of your family members who influences on you. The influence can be good or bad. I don't know how to call that person. He is my model?! Not sure, this is what I get from looking up dictionary.

Comment: Are you after a word for the person or for the action of following them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm looking for a better word than "inspirer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457707/im-looking-for-a-better-word-than-inspirer) Or [I want to be like my father in the future. What would he be called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235535/i-like-to-be-like-my-father-in-the-future-what-would-he-be-called/235536#235536) Or [Word / expression for copying someone who inspires you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220831/word-expression-for-copying-someone-who-inspires-you/220834#220834)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person is your

> **role model**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A person looked to by others as an example to be imitated.
> *The kids look up to Rocky as a folk hero and role model.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/role_model)

Comment: ELU already has quite sufficient 'role model's.

Answer (score 0):

Some would call that a ***mentor*** (or *[guru](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guru)*). Technically to be a mentor involves being a role model for the mentee:

> A mentor may share with a mentee (or protege) information about his or her own career path, as well as provide *guidance, motivation, emotional support, and role modeling*. ([Washington.edu](https://www.washington.edu/doit/what-role-mentor))

But it is used even in negative contexts as a synonym of ***[role model](https://www.google.com/search?q=role%20model%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvIksVfoqRq2bqeUYSOVWQIaKCS-sg%3A1630738362431&source=hp&ei=uhczYYTDF8rIaI3puugO&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYTMlyi-wXLZuY8i7Z2VI-_4W_a-1Dn-C&oq=role%20model&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDIFCAAQgAQyBQguEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggILhCxAxCDAToLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQowI6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOgsILhCABBDHARCjAlC7BlibEWD7HmgAcAB4AIAB3gGIAcEJkgEFNi4yLjKYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*** (which only has positive connotations), as in this title:

> - Notorious thief a mentor to accused Stamford bank robber ([Source](https://www.stamfordadvocate.com/policereports/article/Stamford-bank-robbery-suspect-confessed-to-police-11078961.php))

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for might be "**charismatic**".

> exercising a compelling charm which inspires devotion in others ~Oxford Dictionaries

You might call **person A** *charismatic* because they seem "cool" no matter what or why they do something. (Elon Musk, perhaps? ;-))

Answer (score 0):

If your are following the person's published or otherwise stated philosophy, religious revelation or path through life then you could be called a 'disciple' or 'follower'.

If however you have just been inspired by them and have taken to dressing like them, talking like them and aspire to live in the same kind of house and drive the same model of car then you are said to be "aping" them.

If you become so obsessed with them that you follow them home to try and talk to them then you are "stalking" them. Stop it before they have you arrested.